# In my userinfo command how should i do that I don’t have to use the ID of the person and ping them. It will show the info of the person using the cmd

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make it so when i execute the command without pinging or using the ID of the person it will show the userinfo of the person using the command.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check `message.mentions.members.first()`. If it's undefined then use the message's author - `message.author`.

But it's hard to help and give suggestions without showing us what you have made so far.

Comment: `message.mentions.members.first()` wouldn't be null, it would be either a `GuildMember` or `undefined`